# shell_exec cannot return output of the dig command

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to get the output of the dig command with `shell_exec()`.

This is what I have:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
echo shell_exec("dig google.com AAAA");
?>
```

As stated above, `shell_exec()` is unable to return the output of the `dig` command:

```
$ curl http://localhost/test.php
(no output)
```

although the command itself works fine:

```
$ dig google.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> google.com AAAA
[...]

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     229 IN  AAAA    2404:6800:4007:805::200e
[...]

;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

Redirecting it works as expected, too:

```
$ dig google.com AAAA > ~/f1.txt
$ cat ~/f1.txt

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> google.com AAAA
[...]

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     229 IN  AAAA    2404:6800:4007:805::200e
[...]

;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

However, when I replace the `dig` command with any other command, things work perfectly:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
echo shell_exec("uname -a");
?>

$ curl http://localhost/test.php
Linux lubuntu0 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:49 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Why is `shell_exec()` not working for the `dig` command but working normally for the other commands; and how can I make it work?

---

**Edit**: The output of `curl -v` as requested by @choult for `shell_exec("dig google.com AAAA")`:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost/test.php
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 15:43:01 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/7.0.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/7.0.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.3
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: What happens when you run curl with -v? eg. curl -v http://localhost/test.php

Comment: @choult, please see the edited question for the output of `curl -v`.

Comment: Does `echo shell_exec("dig google.com AAAA 2>&1");` show anything? I would use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) though, you can pass it a variable that will contain all the output and if you give it a returnvar it will contain the exit status.

Comment: @Ciccio: that prints `dig: relocation error: [...]`, so the problem is apparently the fact that there's some problem with the environment. You may want to make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Depending on what exactly the relocation error was, you might want to look into this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119946/can-not-execute-some-shell-command-from-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following show you anyting?

```
echo shell_exec("dig google.com AAAA 2>&1");
```

I would use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) though, you can pass it a variable that will contain all the output and if you give it a returnvar it will contain the exit status.